# tf2 buffer_server timeout and buffer size

Tags: ros, tf2-ros, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm starting the buffer_server with

```
rosrun tf2_ros buffer_server
```

I've seen in [its source code on github](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_ros/src/buffer_server_main.cpp) that one can specify the buffer size through the parameter server.

My questions are: in which measurement unit is the `buffer_size` parameter, what happens when the buffer is overfilled and is the buffer size the same as the duration after which the transform times out?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203512/tf2-buffer_server-timeout-and-buffer-size/) by [gaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/9301/gaya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 311 on 2015-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The buffer size is in seconds. It is how long data will be stored before being removed from the buffer. Roughly this means that you cannot query for data older than that parameter.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1